# Bash multiple commands via `-c` parameter weird signal behavior?

Tags: bash, shell, process, signals

```
bash -c "sleep 5; echo 'test'"
```

If I run the above, and press `CTRL-C` while in the `sleep 5`, it terminates the entire process and `echo 'test'` does NOT get shown.

How can I have the above run and allow the `sleep` command to handle the `SIGINT` (`CTRL-C`)?

I'm guessing the the `SIGINT` is going to the bash process instead of the inner command?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`bash` (and other shell) run scripts without job control, so a ^C will kill the whole script, not just the `sleep` (because they both are part of the same foreground process group).

You should turn job control on in that script with `set -m`:

```
$ bash -c 'set -m; sleep 5; echo test'
^Ctest
$
```

Or *catch* the `SIGINT` signal in the script:

```
$ bash -c 'trap : SIGINT; sleep 5; echo test'
^Ctest
$
```

Notice the `:` instead of `''`; if instead you *ignore* the `SIGINT`, its child processes will inherit that disposition and will ignore it too.

> I'm guessing the the SIGINT is going to the bash process instead of the inner command?

It's going to both of them -- a `VINTR` character (`^C` by default) will send a `SIGINT` signal to all processes from the foreground job (process group).